# How to prevent most disk writes before you trigger a "CrashOnCtrlScroll" crash

Tags: windows, freeze, bsod, crash, debug

You've just enabled a [useful](https://superuser.com/questions/13899/why-does-windows-still-have-the-bsod-on-ctrlscrollscroll-feature) developer feature named [CrashOnCtrlScroll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard).  You've enabled it on your primary machine, which you use every day.  Not on a spare PC, and not on a virtual machine.

For [various reasons](https://superuser.com/questions/1606956/what-to-do-when-crashonctrlscroll-doesnt-seem-to-work), some people struggle to get the feature to work.

You want to test the feature out, to make sure that it works for you.  You'll see whether or not it can crash successfully.

Unfortunately, crashes [might](https://superuser.com/questions/579007/why-unrelated-files-get-corrupted-after-a-blue-screen-of-death-caused-by-audio-d) occasionally cause data loss and/or data corruption.  Therefore, you want to crash the machine at a time when it's probably idle.  You don't want to crash it while it's writing to disk.

How can you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reboot into [Safe Mode with Command Prompt](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2304-boot-into-safe-mode-windows-10-a.html).  While in this mode, your machine will write to disk much less, if at all.

CrashOnCtrlScroll still works fine in this mode.